# Difference of Exponential order statistics

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

> Let $L(\xi) = \Gamma(1,1)$.
>
> $Y_r=(n-r+1)(X_{(r)}-X_{(r-1)}), \ r=1, \dotsc n$
> $(X_{(0)}=0)$
>
> where $X_{(r)}$ - order statistic.
> Prove random variables $Y_r$ independent and have same distribution $f(x)=e^{-x}$

I know joint distribution $g_{r_1,r_2, \dotsc,r_n}(x_1, \dotsc,x_n) = n! f(x_1)f(x_2) \dotsm f(x_n)$,

Jacobian of the transformation $J(x_1, \dotsc,x_n) = n!$

I know if I use variable substitution I should use: $\phi(y) = f(h^{-1}(y))/|J(h^{-1}(y))|$

But I don't know how to get $h^{-1}$. How to get it?

And I'm not sure what's it $h(x)$ here( i can guess it $Y_r$ , but it takes both $X_{(r)} \ and \  X_{r-1}$)

Comment: Are there not simpler ways to express a Gamma(1,1) distribution? Further, you have not linked the order statistic $X_{(r)}$ to the parent distribution. I would also suggest changing your title to something like: Difference of Exponential order statistics